# How do I connect web3py to Amazon manage blockchain?

Tags: web3.py

Currently, I used the following python codes to connect to web3

```
from web3 import Web3
# Fill in your infura API key here
infura_url = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/<INFURA_KEY>"
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))
```

I am now using AWS managedblockchain, it gives me this credential:

```
Node ID
nd-GFJL!JJDANSANJQWEQNDSA
Blockchain instance type
bc.t3.large
Availability zone
us-east-1f
WebSocket EndpointInfo
nd-ajdsojasdnqkebjb1k2jbj.wss.ethereum.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
HTTP EndpointInfo
nd-zVfjoaisjodbqiwubjud.ethereum.managedblockchain.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
ARN
arn:aws:managedblockchain:us-east-1:871628371628:nodes/nd-JASDOIOWQEBJABKJA
```

How do I used this information to access web3 using web3py?

Comment: what you did should be the minimum in order to connect to your provider. be sure that you can access the provider in the first place. i tried accessing the link u posted but it returned 404.

Comment: they provided private key and public key, do you know how could i use it?