# What would be a better Infura node alternative?

Tags: infura

What would be the current best Infura Node alternative? I need to make a large number of requests every day. The current Infura node is too expensive for a large number of requests..

Answer (score 3):

Your better solution is a cluster of local nodes. Your node choice should be a light node if you are only reading data and have enough bandwidth.

the Geth ethereum node can handle more than 10000 requests per second very well but it might crash if not enough memory is available, so keep an eye on that.

I would say 4 nodes with a server with 50GB RAM and 6 CPU cores, is your ideal configuration.

Comment: I found this AWS service to create my own node... But I could not use web3py to connect it... Are you able to help? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101401/how-do-i-connect-web3py-to-amazon-manage-blockchain Thanks!

Comment: I would advise against using light nodes. Lightserve (the setting you active on a full node to serve merkle proofs to light nodes) is off by default afaik on all nodes, so there isn't much availability and it would be slow. You would need to at least use a full node (fast/snap sync would be fine)